# How can you make the Court Chaplain a Cannibal?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I'm trying to unlock the Cathar Cannibalism Major Decision:
[image]

However, I don't know the best way to get a Court Chaplain who shares my tastes. Is there a good way to get a chaplain with the cannibalism trait?

Comment: One of my player-characters became a cannibal due to an event once, but that event seemed to be really random.

Comment: @Philipp That's been my experience as well, so I've had trouble figuring out a reliable way to cause this decision to be achievable

Comment: Likely the best approach is to try to learn as many secrets as possible from your courtiers, and when one of them happens to be a cannibal, then make them Chaplain

Comment: I don't think Cathars allow for appointing Bishops?